# REST API method that accepts multiple file uploads and additional arguments

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm attempting to create a REST API method that accepts multiple file uploads with some additional arguments. This API method will be called from both web forms, web services or mobile apps.

Is there a standard I should be following with regards to how the method takes these parameters in?

So far, I've considered the following two approaches:

1. **JSON body**: file data to be included as base64 encoded fields within the JSON object. Fine if being called from other web services, but troublesome when calling from a HTML form?
2. **multipart/form-data**: easy to use with HTML forms, but problematic when calling from web services or mobile apps?

I know that either of the two approaches would work, but I'd like to implement this the *correct* way (if there is one) according to current standards. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're posting files to the server via `multipart/form-data`, why can't you convert them to `base64` on the server before passing off to your `API`?

Comment: @RyanWilson I can do either. I'm just trying to figure out what the "right" approach is if I'm expecting this API to be accessed from HTML forms, web services and mobile apps.

Comment: Your post says this about `JSON` body: "Fine if being called from other web services, but troublesome when calling from a HTML form?" - Why is it troublesome with forms? You could also create two `API` endpoints and accept the files in different ways to fit your user's interface.

Comment: @RyanWilson Web development isn't my strong suit, so when I said that it would be troublesome, that was an assumption on my part. Do modern JS libraries/frameworks make it easy to POST HTML forms to web APIs as JSON objects? Or does that conversion from HTML form -> JSON body have to be done manually?

Answer (score 0):

> Do modern JS libraries/frameworks make it easy to POST HTML forms to web APIs as JSON objects

Yes, we have a lot of library to convert the file into base64.

In my opinion, choose what is based on your requirement. Firstly, exchanging data in multipart format should be more efficient than base64 json string. But this [article](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/) show, the term of the size is little.

But if we use json, you could pass multiple other variable in the json format and we could read it easily.

Besides, if your file is image, the browser understand data URIs (base64 encoded images), there is no need to transform these if the client is a browser.

Comment: Sorry, restful service is  a just a service not related with the request format. I have deleted the related.